# unsigned int storing signed value

Tags: c

Coming from a typeless language (PHP) I'm a bit confused about datatypes in C. I'm facing the following strange behavior.

```
//First case
unsigned int a;
a = -1;
printf("a = %u", a); //Outputs a strange number, no problem here

//Second case
unsigned int a;
a = -1;
printf("a = %d", a); //Outputs -1
```

What I don't understand is how `a` "contained" a signed value after we specifically said it's `unsigned`?

How can only formatting the output in the second case do that?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't switch them?

Comment: I guess you have swapped two output?

Comment: Oh yeah, I think I swapped them.. thanks guys

Comment: Read about integer overflow. If you -1 from unsigned datatype that is zero, you'll get largest possible number its able to store.

Comment: @quarry, that's why I specificaly wrote in the comment that I don't have a problem with the large number, I'm aware of that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-1` will be represented as something like `10000000 00000000 00000000 00000001` (if `int` has 4 bytes as in my case). When you are outputting it with `%d`, the `printf()` interprets it as a *normal int*, thus it interprets the leading `1` as the sign, and prints `-1`. If you output it as `%u`, `printf()` knows it's unsigned, and interprets the leading `1` as `2^32`, resulting in `4294967295` as output.

Comment: So `printf()` will "translate" those bits to the specified format. Thank you.

Comment: No, -1 will rather be respresented as 11111111... The number 0x8000000 corresponds to -2,147 billion on a two's complement computer.

Comment: @Lundin, oh yes, I've just remembered something about how the sign bit means that the other bits are `NOT`ed, or something like that. Thank you a bunch.

Comment: @Adnan Yeah you could put it like that, hence the name two's _complement_, I would imagine.

Comment: @Lundin Not necessarily, C allows signed magnitude for signed variables. But most systems use 2-complement system.

Answer (score 4):

As other already said you must always keep in mind the difference between a value and its representation, since in C these two concepts are widely separated.

With assignment you put a value into a specific area of memory; with printf() and similar you try to interpret such value.

For clarification try to understand this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {   
    int val = 2181448;;
    printf("%s\n", ((char*)&val));   // * Outputs: "HI!"
    return 0;
}
```

This will print "HI!" because with the assignment you put in a contiguous area of memory ('int' is at least 4 bytes wide here) the number "2181448", which in hexadecimal is 0x00214948, that is:

- a byte with value 0x00, that is zero
- a byte with value 0x21, that is 33 in decimal, that is '!' in ascii
- a byte with 0x49, that is 73 in decimal, that is 'I' in ascii
- and finally a byte with value 0x48 that is 72 in decimal that is 'H' in ascii.

If you make printf interpret it as a string (note that the cast is only to avoid compiler warnings) (*due to reverse endianess) you see outputted such number as a 4-length string zero-terminated 'H' 'I' '!' '\0'

Answer (score 3):

Because that is what `printf` does. It *doesn't know the type* of the supplied values. So it will take the data it finds in `a` and interpret it as a signed integer, because you tell it to do so by giving it `%d`.

`printf` can also be quite dangerous if you put in the incorrect values for formatting codes, or completely omit them. Your program will crash without any message.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will translate -1 to the correct signed number format for your system, in 99.9% of all cases this will be two's complement. On a two's complement system with 32 bit ints, -1 will correspond to 0xFFFFFFFF. But if you store that in an unsigned variable, you will get the value 4.29 billion.

You then attempt to print 4.29 billion using the %d format specifier, which is reserved for negative numbers. The program then interprets 0xFFFFFFFF as -1 again.

To sum it up, there is no such thing as negative numbers on a binary level. Depending on how you chose to display the binary, you can form negative numbers. Still, it is all just ones and zeroes: you cannot save a minus sign in a computer memory cell.

Comment: Not a very qualified answer, much of guess work. No, assigning `-1` to an unsigned is not, UB, never. Unsigned integer types have a well defined arithmetic that is imposed by the standard: they wrap around. This is completely different from signed types where over- or underflow can cause you serious problems.

Comment: @JensGustedt Fair enough, I wasn't certain, therefore the "probably". I have removed that part.